# Android SDK installion missing with android studio exe

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I tried installing the android studio but when I start installing, Android SDK is not shown in the available list.

[image]

Comment: explain your problem clearly this is not the place where android sdk will be shown

Comment: maybe the same version is already installed in your machine

Comment: Check the answer below , and let me know if you still face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just `Click on Next Button` , and All the required SDKs will be downloaded next automatically.

& then

To check the `Android SDK` , `open android studio` and `click on SDK Manager` ,this will launch the standalone Window like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is shown in the list, the fact that it is greyed out is because you cannot uncheck it, it is a requirement without which android studio cannot work, do not worry just tap on next and it will install all the required things